# Recursively building an XML tree using dom4j without duplicate code for the root node

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I am serializing a tree structure to XML data.
My tree looks like

```
Company
  Department
    Employee
    Employee
```

My desired root node is `Company`, so the XML would look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Company>
  <Department>
    <Employee>
       ...
    </Employee>
  </Department>
</Company>
```

After looking at the examples, I've decided I'll write it like this

```
public void writeNodes(Element root, NodeBase node) throws XMLStreamException
{
    Element elmt = root.addElement(node.getName());
    for (NodeBase child : node.getChildren())
    {
        writeNodes(child);
    }
}

public void makeXML(NodeCompany root, String filename)
{
    try {
        document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();            
        writeNodes(???, root);
        writeFile(document, filename);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want my root node to be used as the root, but I don't want to write duplicate code to treat the root node separately from its children.

Since there will ever only be a single Company node in my tree, I can perform an explicit check in my `writeNodes` method to skip any company nodes, but that doesn't look nice.

Is there a way to complete this code without duplicating any code?

Comment: What is the purpose for which you will use this xml file? Would use of JSON be helpful?  One note from experience: whenever someone says "there will never more than one ..." design for multiple. (You may even want to use "Company x" and "Company textX" as two companies to test changes in functionality during the life of your project / product.

Comment: Our specification says there will only be one. Any more and it is invalid data. I do not think it would be necessary to design for the possibility that the specs change (since they haven't changed for 20 years). The XML is used because other tools expect XML and we're the only ones that are still using an old serialization format.

Comment: JSON is an encoding of XML (with additional mechanisms to encode / decode Java objects ... including the simple structure you have (reducing the amount of code you have to write).

Comment: The XML exporter I've written is already pretty small (20 lines, 4 methods), except it treats the root node separately from its children. JSON might be cool but I'm not willing to go and ask everyone else to accept JSON.

Comment: That is fine .. JSON just is a particular format of XML (Company contains array of Department contains array of Employee).

Comment: I don't think JSON is a subset of XML, in the sense that XML is a subset of SGML.

Comment: You are right, JSON is not a subset of xml ..just defines a particular xml format.

Comment: JSON and XML are two completely different serialization formats. There is no "particular XML" format. XML is XML. I don't expect an XML parser to accept JSON data, nor would I consider JSON to be valid XML, so I don't think it would be fine to just choose to write JSON and hope XML parsers will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

for me the method writeNodes is unnecessary, you can do this:

```
public void makeXML(Element rootElement, String filename) {
    try {

        //you must detach it for you can add it in the new document after
        Element rootElementCopied = (Element) rootElement.clone();

        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();


        document.add(rootElementCopied);

        writeFile(document, filename);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```